# react js: install downloaded apk

Tags: reactjs

I am playing around with reactjs and wanted to prompt an apk install, similar to how you would prompt a .zip download, I have:

```
return (
                    <div className="card border-0 flex-row flex-wrap p-0 m-0" style={{background:'none'}}>
                        <div className="col-2 p-0 m-0">
                            <div className="card-header border-0 m-0 mt-1 p-0">
                                <img className="imgBorder" src={require('./assets/img/car.jpg')} width={'95.6dp'} height={'119.5dp'} alt=""/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-10">
                            <div className="card-block align-items-center p-0 m-0">
                                <h4 className="card-title" style={{color:'white', fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{this.props.title}</h4>
                                <p className="card-text pl-5 mb-0" style={{color:'white', lineHeight:'1'}}>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit...</p>
                                <p className="muted m-0 p-0" style={{color:'white', lineHeight:'1.4', fontSize:'80%'}}>05/05/20</p>
                                <a href={this.props.url} className="playBtn my-2"><SportsEsportsIcon /><Trans i18nKey='library.play'>Play</Trans> </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="w-100"></div>
                    </div>
                );
```

and the `href={this.props.url}` is pointing to a server with a `.apk` file. However, when I install the app (PWA), instead of prompting for download, I get taken to the url where the file is. Anyway I can trigger the download?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the `download` attribute on the link, versus linking *to* the location alone.

[Attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes)

`download`

> Prompts the user to save the linked URL instead of navigating to it.
> Can be used with or without a value

```
<a
  href={this.props.url}
  className="playBtn my-2"
  download
  // or download="myAwesomeApp.apk" if you wanted to provide a name hint
>
  <SportsEsportsIcon />
  <Trans i18nKey='library.play'>
    Play
  </Trans>
</a>
```